# subset in data.table when groups are empty

Tags: r, data.table

For these data

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(id=1:12, group=rep(1:3, each=4), x=rnorm(12))

> dat
    id group           x
 1:  1     1  1.37095845
 2:  2     1 -0.56469817
 3:  3     1  0.36312841
 4:  4     1  0.63286260
 5:  5     2  0.40426832
 6:  6     2 -0.10612452
 7:  7     2  1.51152200
 8:  8     2 -0.09465904
 9:  9     3  2.01842371
10: 10     3 -0.06271410
11: 11     3  1.30486965
12: 12     3  2.28664539
```

My goal is to get, from each group, the first id for which `x` is larger than some threshold, say `x>1.5`.

```
> dat[x>1.5, .SD[1], by=group]
   group id        x
1:     2  7 1.511522
2:     3  9 2.018424
```

is indeed correct but I am unhappy about that fact that it silently yields no result for group 1. Instead, I would like it to yield the last id of each group for which no id fulfills the condition. I see that I could achieve this in two steps

```
> tmp <- dat[x>1.5, .SD[1], by=group]
> rbind(tmp,dat[!group%in%tmp$group,.SD[.N], by=group])
   group id         x
1:     2  7 1.5115220
2:     3  9 2.0184237
3:     1  4 0.6328626
```

but I am sure I am not making full use of the data.table capabilities here, which must permit a more elegant solution.

Comment: For information, the reason it doesn't yield a result for 1 is because the first part (`x>1.5`) filters the data.table, so the group 1 doesn't exist in the data.table anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, we can check for a condition and subset row by group.

```
library(data.table)
dat[dat[, if(any(x>1.5)) .I[which.max(x > 1.5)] else .I[.N], by=group]$V1]

#   id group         x
#1:  4     1 0.6328626
#2:  7     2 1.5115220
#3:  9     3 2.0184237
```

The `dplyr`, translation of that would be

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(if(any(x > 1.5)) which.max(x > 1.5) else n())
```

---

Or more efficiently

```
dat[, .SD[{temp = x > 1.5; if (any(temp)) which.max(temp) else .N}], by = group]
```

Thanks to @IceCreamTouCan, @sindri_baldur and @jangorecki for their valuable suggestions to improve this answer.

Comment: Or simplify to: `dat[, .SD[if (any(x > 1.5)) which.max(x > 1.5) else .N], by=group]`

Comment: do not use `x > 1.5` multiple times, it is inefficient, use `{` in `j, compute `x > 1.5` once, assign to temp var and re-use

Comment: I agree that the approach without a join seems more intuitive. Can you add it to the solution, including Jan's suggestion (which I don't get)?

Comment: @bumblebee okay..I have updated the answer based on the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could subset both ways (which are optimized by GForce) and then combine them:

```
D1 = dat[x>1.5, lapply(.SD, first), by=group]
D2 = dat[, lapply(.SD, last), by=group]
rbind(D1, D2[!D1, on=.(group)])

   group id         x
1:     2  7 1.5115220
2:     3  9 2.0184237
3:     1  4 0.6328626
```

There is some inefficiency here since we are grouping by `group` three times. I'm not sure if that will be outweighed by more efficient calculations in `j` thanks to GForce or not. @jangorecki points out that the inefficiency of grouping three times might be mitigated by setting the key first.

*Comment*: I used last(.SD) since .SD[.N] is not yet optimized and last(.SD) throws an error. I changed the OP's code to use lapply first for the sake of symmetry.

Comment: `setkey` on `group` would probably give speed up if we want to group by that column three times

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
dat[x>1.5 | group!=shift(group, -1L), .SD[1L], .(group)]
```